# Is there a way to retrieve field value from rlon rlat coordinate system?

Tags: python

I'm struggling to retrieve, by the fastest way possible, the value of a grid point in an rlat/rlon coordinate system.
To be more precise. I have a field from CORDEX (temperature field), with latitude (rlat/rlon 2D field) and longitude (rlat/rlon 2D field).
[image]

It's like a kind of meshgrid system i presume, with x and y 2d fields.

My first question is : is there a way to retrieve the field value with an lat/lon simple coordinate (for example for the point lat= 45 and lon= -73). I don't know how to handle the 2d coordinate system at this stage.

In the other hand i have a lot of observations stations to compare with the temperature field. I have tried with a kd tree system but it's way too slow for my task.

All the replies are welcome,
thanks to all !

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question